# Log Authorization (Basic, Digest..) for a site from a Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a extension for Chrome that will log some user activity on the browser for processing that info afterwards and I need to save the info related to basic http auth  when the user being tracked enters its user and password on the browser basic auth dialog for that website.

This is the data I need:

```
Authorization url
A partial or complete URL that matches one or more HTTP Request URLs
Ex: www.urlbase.com

Authorization username
The username to authorize.
Ex: admin

Authorization password
The password for the user
Ex: 123456

Authorization domain
The domain to use for NTLM.

Authorization realm
The realm to use for NTLM.
```

I have come across:

https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/privacy
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/certificateProvider
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions

But none of them seem to even talk about http auth.

Is there really any way from the chrome extension API or from Javascript to get that info?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is allowed to get private credentials.

As mentioned in [Tutorial: OAuth](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth),

> [OAuth](https://oauth.net/) provides a mechanism for users to grant access to private data without sharing their private credentials (username/password).

You may want to also check [Developer Program Policies](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/program_policies) specifically [User Data Privacy](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/program_policies#userdata) regarding your concern.

Hope that helps!